# Passing request parameters to ResourceHandler

Tags: servlets, jetty

I have a ServletContextHandler:

```
public class MyHandler extends ServletContextHandler {

  public MyHandler() throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
    setContextPath("/path");        

    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.jsp" });

    URL resource = SwiftSocialMessenger.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resource");

    resourceHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(resource.toURI().normalize()));

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resourceHandler });
    this.setHandler(handlers);
}
```

}

I need the request parameters in index.jsp page for example:

```
<html>
  .....
 <body>
   <span title=<%= request.getParameter("param") %> </span>
 </body>
<html>
```

Is it possible to get the request parameter using Resource Handler?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Constantly adjusting the ResourceHandler.baseResource with each request isn't a sane solution (api abuse).  The `ResourceHandler` is for serving static content directly to the requesting client.  JSP does not participate in the jetty side static file serving as well.

Comment: My purpose is to serve an html file, but that html file should contain a dynamic data which is fetched from the request url.